# tesseract crashes with fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 on Android

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I'm working with this library (tess_two) for a few weeks and everything was good. But today Tesseract starts crashes with this error A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 31890 (Thread-13571). Nothing have changed from yesterday, same phone, same code. Crashes on method getUTF8Text()

Last logs:

```
10-31 11:31:05.879 31029-31890/ru.ckdigital.priceconverter E/OcrRecognizeAsyncTask: thresholding completed. converting to bmp. size:432x256
10-31 11:31:05.884 31029-31890/ru.ckdigital.priceconverter I/Leptonica(native): Writing 32bpp RGBA bitmap (w=432, h=256, stride=1728) from 1bpp Pix (wpl=14)
10-31 11:31:06.375 31029-31890/ru.ckdigital.priceconverter A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 31890 (Thread-13571)
```

backtrace from tombstone file:

```
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0001764c  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
    #01 pc 0003fc6b  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL33__pthread_cond_timedwait_relativeP23pthread_cond_internal_tP15pthread_mutex_tPK8timespec+56)
    #02 pc 0001f0b7  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #03 pc 00010139  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+112)
    #04 pc 0005e2fb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+70)
    #05 pc 0003fe4b  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
    #06 pc 00019c85  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```